# Java log throwable only in debug mode

Tags: java, logging

I want make log with throwable only when log-level is under debug mode.

My way is

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (Exception e){
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.warn("ERR Occurs", e);
    } else {
        logger.warn("ERR Occurs");
    }
}
```

But it is hard to change all my code and It is difficult to see the code at a glance

Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Going forward, the best way to do this is to have a specific log class that you pass your parameters/error into, and let it manage the details like your method above (Rather than typing it out hundreds of times), for example `Log.add("message", e, level);` or `Log.warn("message", e);` etc. The advantage of a log class is that you can also change the way it works at any stage without modifying any other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpler one line equivalent to your own:

```
logger.warn("ERR Occurs", logger.isDebugEnabled() ? e : null);
```

You might consider packaging the ternary operator as a simple static method `logEx(e)` if not wanting to override the logging class.

However: hiding exceptions is a bad idea - especially when not in debug mode, so you are better off with addressing the conditions causing the exception and leaving the logging as:

```
logger.warn("ERR Occurs", e);
```